# What is the difference between these two lines of code

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc, allocation

What is the difference between:

```
p = (int*) malloc (5*sizeof(int));
```

vs

```
int *ptr = new int[5];
```

Is the top one C's version of memory allocation for a pointer to point to create a spot in memory for 5 integers? Then the bottom is C++'s version? Where do they appear in memory (if they do).

Comment: depends on the implementation.  The C++ library's default `operator new` might just call `malloc` under the hood, or it might not.  It might also allocate extra space to track the array size, invisibly to the user program.

Comment: For `int`s, not a lot. But try doing that for non-POD types (over-simplifying, "types that have constructors") and the difference will be huge, since `malloc` does not know it should call the constructor in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both allocates size bytes of uninitialized storage and return a pointer to it. Both snippets works on C++, but the `new` one is exclusive for C++. Implementation of both depends on the compiler. When using `malloc()` function, always use `free()` function to free memory. When using `new` operator, always use `delete` operator to free memory. Never mix the pairs.

`new` can offer some other features like being overloaded and call a non-primitive type constructor. [See](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

In both examples you gave, memory will be allocated sequentially.

Comment: Are both allocated onto the heap?

Comment: The dynamic memory is allocated on the heap and the pointer itself is allocated on the stack for both types of allocation.

Comment: And in the case of using `new[]`, always use `delete[]`, not `delete`.  Of course, usually you should just avoid using `new[]`/`delete[]` altogether.

Comment: So C++ operators, "new" and "delete" are used for allocating dynamic memory. While on the other hand in the C language, instead the functions malloc is used to allocate dynamic memory. I can use malloc in C++ and C but that is not the case for new/delete.